# Null Pointer Exception Occurs only while comparison and not printing out values

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, comparison

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("595231gov_nov_13_assessed.txt"));
    BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("627231farsidetect.txt"));


      String Id = null;

     int count = 0;
     String count_line=null;
      while((count_line = in1.readLine()) != null){
          if(count_line.contains("ID: "))
              count ++;
      }
      System.out.println(count);
      File1 [] File_1 = new File1[count];
      in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("595231gov_nov_13_assessed.txt"));




     int i = 0;
     String line = null;
     String relation = null;
     while ((line = in1.readLine()) != null && i != count){
         if(line.contains("ID:")){
             File_1 [i] = new File1();
             File_1[i].ID = line;
         }
         else if(line.contains("Relation:")){
             File_1[i].Relation = line;
         }
         else if(line.contains("Result:")){
             File_1[i].Result = line;
             i ++;
         }
         else if(line.contains("TP") || line.contains("FP") || line.contains("TN") || line.contains("FN")){
             File_1[i-1].Comment = line;
         }

     }


    line = null;
    relation = null;



     i =0; 
     int count2 = 0;
     count_line=null;
      while((count_line = in2.readLine()) != null){
          if(count_line.contains("ID: "))
              count2 ++;
      }
      System.out.println(count2);
      in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/627231farsidetect.txt"));
      File2 [] File_2 = new File2[count2];


    while ((line = in2.readLine()) != null && i != count2){
         if(line.contains("ID:")){
             File_2 [i] = new File2();
             File_2[i].ID = line;
         }
         else if(line.contains("Relation:")){
             File_2[i].Relation = line;
         }
         else if(line.contains("Result:")){
             File_2[i].Result = line;
             i ++;
         }

     }


    in1.close();
    in2.close();

    for (i=0; i<File_1.length - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(File_1[i].ID);
        System.out.println(File_1[i].Relation);
        System.out.println(File_1[i].Result);
        if(File_1[i].Comment != null)
            System.out.println(File_1[i].Comment);
    }



    for (i=0; i<File_2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(File_2[i].ID);
        System.out.println(File_2[i].Relation);
        System.out.println(File_2[i].Result);
    }





    for (i = 0; i < File_1.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=0;j< File_2.length; i++){
            if(File_1[i].ID != null && File_2[j].ID != null && File_1[i].Relation != null && File_2[j].Relation !=null){
            if(File_1[i].ID.equals(File_2[j].ID) && File_1[i].Relation.equals(File_2[j].Relation)){
                if(!(File_1[i].Result.equals(File_2[j].Result))){
                    System.out.println(File_1[i].ID);
                    System.out.println(File_1[i].Relation);
                    System.out.println(File_1[i].Result);
                    if(File_1[i].Comment != null)
                        System.out.println(File_1[i].Comment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }



}

public static class File1{
public String ID;
public String Relation;
public String Result;
public String Comment;
        public File1() {
        this.Result = null;
        this.ID=null;
        this.Relation = null;
        this.Comment = null;
    }
}

public static class File2{
public String ID;
public String Relation;
public String Result;

    public File2() {
        this.Result = null;
        this.ID=null;
        this.Relation = null;
    }

}
```

-When I just printout the values, I do not face a null pointer exception, 
-But when I try and do comparison I am faced with a null pointer exception and I can't figure out why. 
-NetBeans just points to the comparison statement

```
if(File_1[i].ID.equals(File_2[j].ID) && File_1[i].Relation.equals(File_2[j].Relation))
```

Something else which is unusual is that, I have assigned values for File_1 until File_1[Length] but it prints out length - 1 values. Whereas I assigned values for File_2 the same way and it prints fine. Please help. I am processing Farsi text, so there might be the possibility of weird characters, but I am pretty sure there has to be something to do with the index values.

Comment: Please provide enough code to run and reproduce.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on "complete").

Comment: What is printed out when you print the values?

Comment: What is in the stacktrace? Looks like your loop is actually wrong: `for(int j=0;j< File_2.length; i++){` ... you really want to increment `i` instead of `j` here?

Comment: @donfuxx *banging my head on the wall* THank YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it was intentional or not, but in your for loop you seem to be incrementing the wrong value (i instead of j)...

```
for (i = 0; i < File_1.length-1; i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j< File_2.length; j++)
   {
      if(File_1[i].ID != null && File_2[j].ID != null && File_1[i].Relation != null && File_2[j].Relation !=null)
      {
         if(File_1[i].ID.equals(File_2[j].ID) && File_1[i].Relation.equals(File_2[j].Relation))
         {
            if(!(File_1[i].Result.equals(File_2[j].Result)))
            {
               System.out.println(File_1[i].ID);
               System.out.println(File_1[i].Relation);
               System.out.println(File_1[i].Result);
               if(File_1[i].Comment != null)
                  System.out.println(File_1[i].Comment);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```